# How would this look as an one-liner?

Tags: perl

How should something like this be written as an one-liner?

I would be temped to just take everything inside the `while`-loop and `perl -e '...' data`, but is there a better way, then having `if`-statements?

```
open(F, '<', 'data') or die $!;

while (my $line = <F>) {

    if ($line =~ m/test /) {
        my @a = split / /, $line;
        printf("%2s %4s %4s\n", substr($a[1], 1), $a[2], substr($a[5], 0, -1));
    } else {
        print $line;
    }

}

close F;
```

Comment: "How should something like this be written as an one-liner?" All of the above? Pretty unreadable I tells ya

Comment: Very hard to read, and a nightmare to maintain is how it would look, for sure.

Comment: @KenWhite Are there any guide lines on when something would (should) be a one-liner?

Comment: The general rule is that you never sacrifice readability and maintainability just to save space, IMO. If you (or someone taking over your code in the future) can't figure out what it means six months down the road, brevity is meaningless.

Comment: @KenWhite Would it be safe to say, if it contains an if-statement, then don't one-line?

Comment: No, you can't say that; there are times that an `if` statement might be a candidate for one-lining. But you have something fairly large (and easily readable/maintainable) that it's doubtful would gain anything (other than complexity and fewer LOC) by being one-lined.

Comment: Unless you have a desire to set yourself a personal challenge (in which case you wouldn't be asking for help here) *always* aim for clarity first and brevity and efficiency last.

Comment: `ls -la` is a one-liner (not Perl, of course).  If you don't mind re-typing it rather than re-running something pre-written, it's ok as a one-liner.  The bar is set wherever you get tired of trying to remember what worked last time. :)  Not a terrible question, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something ugly like:

```
perl -anle 'printf("%2s %4s %4s", substr($F[1], 1), $F[2], substr($F[5], 0, -1)),next if grep /test/, @F;print'
```

maybe? But why would you want to use an one-liner?

Comment: It is easier to put a one-liner in scientific documentation than a script, where I would have to explain how to use the script.

Comment: I can understand the problem. But if you are publishing to non-Perl speakers then you really should provide a link to a working program. Embedding a string of characters that makes no sense to your readers can make you liable for all sorts of damage that a corruption may cause.

Comment: I am glad you explained "why".  My suggestion is to attach a one-paragraph supporting document explaining how to save a text file and type "`perl myapp.pl`" (for example).

Answer (score 6):

First, let's clean up the actual program.

```
while (<>) {
   if (/test/) {
      my @a = split;
      $_ = sprintf("%2s %4s %4s\n", substr($a[1], 1), $a[2], substr($a[5], 0, -1));
   }

   print;
}
```

Then, it becomes easy to take advantage of `-p` and `-a` ("make a one-liner").

```
perl -pale'$_ = sprintf("%2s %4s %4s", substr($F[1], 1), $F[2], substr($F[5], 0, -1)) if /test/' data
```

Comment: Note that `split ' '` (what I used), is not quite the same `split / /` (what you used), but it's probably what you really want anyway.

Comment: I was going to say that to the other answer (which implicitly does `split ' '`), but I couldn't think of a practical difference in this particular case, other than fewer warnings on bad data.